# Why do fonts render at larger sizes in 18.04?

Tags: fonts, 18.04

Here is a screenshot of the Xfce appearence settings in 18.04 (left) compared to 16.04 (right):

[image: screensot showing fonts]

As you can see, the same font, font size, hinting, and DPI is selected.

In the bottom right is an overlay of the two showing that the word "Style" renders approximately 1 pixel taller and wider on 18.04. Since it is only 10 pixels tall to begin with this represents a 10% increase in size.

In addition, some other fonts render smaller in 18.04 than they do in 16.04 (not pictured, but they do.)

Why does this happen?

Comment: Possibly related to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1054779/incorrect-font-glyphs-rendering-in-gtk-applications-in-ubuntu-18-04 . I am still investigating the issue.